# override array length in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got an idea to override javascript array length value and wants to return any random value.
let's say..

```
 a=[56,78,89,200,800]
 b=['a','b','f']

 a.length = 2  ;  //should give me only 2;
 b.length = 2  ; //also should give 2
```

Is it possible to change length property and is there any tweaks to change the splice or slice method also.

Comment: Have you tried changing it ?

Comment: Could you just hardcode them to return 2?

Comment: i tried but in vain @Rayon,yes i want that value to be 2 or anything but it should be same value for any array.

Comment: @bharathmuppa, Read [___`array.length`___](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Comment: "*I got an idea to override javascript array length value*" - wrong idea. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: i am just going through all the properties which are writable in array but as per doc it is writable so i tried changing array.length to some value but this is not happening.

Comment: sorry @Bergi now i came to know one point which i missed, in docs "it is writable but not configurable"

Comment: Only it's not an array

Answer (score 2):

`Array.length` is a protected property, **only read**; is a bad idea try to change it.

**Better** you can create your own class; example:

```
var oArray = function (aArr){
    oRet = {};

    for(var i = 0, aArrL = aArr.length; i < aArrL; i++){
        oRet[i] = aArr[i];
    }
    oRet.length = 2;

    return oRet;
};

a= new oArray([56,78,89,200,800]);
b=['a','b','f'];

console.log(a.length);
console.log(b.length);
```

`a` is a custom class, `b` is standard JavaScript Array.

Comment: "Array.length is a protected property, only read; is a bad idea try to change it." No it is not protected, it can be modified and depending on the case it is a pretty good idea to change it such as emptying an array without breaking its references by making it's length = 0;

Comment: You can change the value, like `b.length = 2;` (and delete the last value), but not to change is behaviour, like `Array.prototype.length = 2;`. Maybe I expressed inexactly.